# Using Python Turtle to create digital typewriter with user input

Tags: list, if-statement, variables, graphics, python-turtle

Im a newer programmer making a program for a highschool assignment. We have to meet a number of criteria but Im using Python Turtle and a series of functions to draw letters using user input. In the program, I define all of the functions for letters A-V (last 4 letters omitted, for time reasons) and I have the following program at the end:

```
type = input("What would you like to type?")


letters = list(type)
tick = 0
tock = 0
y = (letters[tock])
for i in range(len(letters)):
    if y == "a": 
        a()
    elif y == "b":
        b()
    elif y == "c":
        c()
    elif y == "d":
        d()
    elif y == "e":
        e()
    elif y == "f":
        f()
    elif y == "g":
        g()
    elif y == "h":
        h()
    elif y == "i":
        i()
    elif y == "j":
        j()
    elif y == "k":
        k()
    elif y == "l":
        l()
    elif y == "m":
        m()
    elif y == "n":
        n()
    elif y == "o":
        o()
    elif y == "p":
        p()
    elif y == "q":
        q()
    elif y == "r":
        r()
    elif y == "s":
        s()
    elif y == "t":
        t()
    elif y == "u":
        u()
    elif y == "v":
        v()
    elif y == " ":
        space()
    tock = tock + 1
```

right now, tick is not in use. We have never done anything like this and Im reaching out to my teachers for support but not getting much help. I cant find much information on it. What I have set up right now is that it would compile the received text and split it up into characters, where it would then figure out how many characters their are and loop the function that many times, determining what character each part of the user input is and writing the letter using the functions that were determined before.

whats happening whenever I run it is that it will write as many characters as are inputted, but it will all be the first character that is written. Example, if you wrote "hello" it would write "hhhhh"

Ive never made a post here before, Im probably doing a lot wrong. I tried to be as informative as possible, but let me know if you need any information.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the string and in each iteration you can print one letter of the string. With **time module** you can give gap of 1 sec after every letter typed. This would create a typewriting effect.
**Hope so my answer will help you!!**

```
import time
    
query = input("Please tell us what do you want to type: ")

for i in range(len(query)):
    print(query[i], end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```